# How to fix Rasa Nlu Confidence giving 0 if there is an underscore in the word?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying to build simple chatbot application using `Rasa`, but my bot is giving confidence 0 if there is an underscore in the word.

Below is my config.yml configuration:

```
language: en  
pipeline: supervised_embeddings  
policies:  
  - name: KerasPolicy  
  #- name: MappingPolicy  
  #- name: MemoizationPolicy  
  #- name: FallbackPolicy
```

nlu.md configuration:

```
## intent:name
- name
- nmae
- nme
- what is my name?

## intent: firstname
- firstName
- FName
- first name

## intent: gender
- gender
- sex
- gnder
- gendr
- sx

## intent: lastname
- lastName
- lname
- surname
- lstnme
- lstname

## intent: username
- userName
- uname
- usrnme
- usernme
- userid
```

If I pass `firstname` I am getting the correct intent and confidence and if I try with `_firstname` or `first_name` I am getting the below result:

```
first_name
{
  "intent": {
    "name": null,
    "confidence": 0.0
  },
  "entities": [],
  "intent_ranking": [],
  "text": "first_name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 0 confidence precisely because you've used underscore in your word. The word `first_name` hasn't been used in your training data so, that word is foreign to your model. That's why it doesn't predict anything for that word. (By default, it uses a `whitespace tokenizer` so words are only tokenized by whitespace.)

So, to fix your issue, just don't use underscore in your word or you can edit the whitespace tokenizer to tokenize by whitespace and underscore.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I'm able to solve this issue by using **CountVectorsFeaturizer**  with analyzer 'char_wb' .

Comment: There's that way too but I don't really like using the `char_wb` option. I don't think it works that well because I think it'll give more false-positives.